# What is the name for a polynomial with all coefficients equal to 1?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

I am looking for a good google search word for polynomials that have
all coefficients equal to 1.

An example of a such polynomial is:

$$1+x^{23}+x^{57}+x^{101}$$

One such polynomial could also be the special case which is the truncated geometric series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{n=k} x^n$$

but I am more interested in the irregular form as in the example.

What is the name for a polynomial with all coefficients equal to 1?

Comment: May be, one of these days, they will be called Granvik polynomials. Why not ? I am not kidding you, be sure. Cheers :-)

Comment: Maybe you mean all nonzero coefficients equal to one. A polynomial can have only finitely many nonzero coefficients, so there's no polynomial with all equal to one.

Comment: Generating funtion for integers in binary?!

Comment: Last I heard, it was called All One Polynomial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [polynomial with $0$, $1$ coefficients](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22polynomials+with+0%2C+1+coefficients%22), or a [polynomial with coefficients from $\{0,1\}$](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22polynomials%20with%20coefficients%20from%20%7B0%2C%201%7D%22).

A polynomial with all coefficients equal to $1$ would be of the form $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}+x^n$.

Comment: And sometimes [0,1-polynomials](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%220%2C1-polynomials%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5), too.

Answer (score 4):

These are known as *Newman polynomials*. See for example [On Newman and Littlewood polynomials with prescribed number of zeros inside the unit disk](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13994), by K. G. Hare and J. Jankauskas, arXiv:1910.13994.