# How do you solve an equation consisting of a logarithmically chopped subsets of the truncated geometric series, equal to zero?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots, riemann-zeta

The Fourier transform of the Riemann zeta function looks like this:

[image: Fourier transform of Riemann zeta]

The polynomial equation I am interested in solving has the following exponents and coefficients:

[image: logarithmically alternating geometric series]

that is, it is a subset of the geometric series with gaps in it.

Superimposing the polynomial coefficients on the plot of t Fourier transform of Riemann zeta, one gets a match:

[image: superimposed polynomial coefficients on Fourier transform]

The starting point is that Mathematica can transform this equation:

```
 Reduce[1/(E^log1)^x + 1/(E^log2)^x + 1/(E^log3)^x == 0, x]
```

into logarithms of polynomial roots when the variables `log1, log2, log3` are rational numbers.
One finds this same starting point some number theory books. `Reduce` is another version of `Solve`.

With the help of Jeffrey Stopple's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/398389/25104) I found the polynomial  above [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/252896/328).

The polynomial whose coefficients fit into the plot of Fourier transform above has the following
definition:

$$P(x)=\sum _{q=1}^{\frac{m}{2}} \left(\sum _{k=\frac{\text{Round}[h \log (m-(2 q-1))]}{\gcd  h}}^{\frac{\text{Round}[h \log (m-(2 q-2))]}{\gcd  h}-1} x^k\right)$$

where $m$ is some even number greater than $4$.

An abbreviated form of this particular polynomial is:

$$P(x)=1+x+\text{...}+x^{277}+x^{440}+\text{...}+x^{553}+x^{644}+\text{...}+x^{715}+\text{...}+x^{831}+x^{878}+\text{...}+x^{921}=0$$
where dot dot dot means that all the exponents inbetween the numbers are included.

So it is geometric series with holes in it.

*Question:*

> Is there a way of finding solution to equations that have the truncated geometric series with gaps in it?

In case I got it all wrong, here is the associated Mathematica program that is meant to describe what I am looking for. gcd is the greatest common divisor of the rational approximations of the logarithms.

```
(*start*)(*Associated Mathematica program*)
Clear[h, x, k, s, s1, nn, m];
$MaxRootDegree = 1000;
m = 10;(*m must be an even integer and greater than 4*)h = 400;
gcd = GCD @@ Table[Round[Log[n]*h]/h, {n, 1, m}]
Table[Round[Log[n]*h]/h, {n, 1, m}]/gcd
r = 100;
integer = 0;
s = 1/gcd*(2*Pi*I*integer - 
    Log[Root[
      Sum[(-1)^(n + 1) #1^(Round[Log[n]*h]/h/gcd), {n, 1, m}] &, r]])
N[s, 80]
N[Sum[(-1)^(n + 1)/(E^(Round[Log[n]*h]/h))^s, {n, 1, m}]]
s1 = 1/gcd*(2*Pi*I*integer - 
    Log[Root[
      polynomial = 
       Sum[Sum[#1^k, {k, Round[Log[m - (2*q - 1)]*h]/h/gcd, 
           Round[Log[m - (2*q - 2)]*h]/h/gcd - 1}], {q, 1, m/2}] &, 
      r - 1]])
N[s1, 80]
N[Sum[(-1)^(n + 1)/(E^(Round[Log[n]*h]/h))^s1, {n, 1, m}]]
(*end*)

(*start*)
m = 20;
h = 200;
sort = Sort[
  Flatten[Table[
    Table[k, {k, Round[Log[m - (2*q - 1)]*h]/h/gcd, 
      Round[Log[m - (2*q - 2)]*h]/h/gcd - 1}], {q, 1, m/2}]]]
"Plot of exponents of polynomial"
ListLinePlot[sort]
"Plot of coefficients of polynomial"
ListPlot[Sum[
  Table[If[sort[[n]] == k, 1, 0], {k, 1, Max[sort]}], {n, 1, 
   Length[sort]}], Filling -> 0]
(*end*)
```

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4839820/8530